# How to transfer save game from PS4 to PS3?

Tags: ps4, ps3, final-fantasy-10

I had a friend help me with Final Fantasy X on his PS4. I sent him an USB stick to put the save game on it so that I can copy it to my PS3. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It should be possible to do this via data transfer and saving it to the cloud. Kindly check out this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-avTxoum0E) for the steps.